# Split function in JSON/Excel format for Sharepoint online

Tags: json, sharepoint-online

I am using sharepoint online as an image library. I am using 'keywords' to tag each image. The field is a string of delimited values like this:

`keyword1;keyword2;keyword3`

I would like to format this field value by splitting the string using the semi-colon delimiter and showing each keyword in its own span, so its looks like this:

(keyword 1)  (keyword 2)  (keyword 3)

[image: example of how i'd like to split and style the values]

I'm not sure if I need to use a calculated column to do this or if it is even possible? I've tried using 'forEach' but i cannot seem to loop through the items - they just render as a single value in a single span?

This is what i'm using at the moment:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "tileProps": {
    "height": "300",
    "width": "300",
    "formatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "display": "flex",
        "flex-wrap": "wrap",
        "align-items": "stretch",
        "box-shadow": "0 1.6px 3.6px 0 #00000022, 0 0.3px 0.9px 0 #0000001c",
        "min-width": "150px",
        "width": "100%",
        "margin-bottom": "0",
        "border-radius": "3px",
        "margin": "0 2px",
        "background-color": "#fbfbfb",
        "height": "350px"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "display": "flex",
            "flex-wrap": "wrap",
            "position": "relative",
            "padding-bottom": "30px",
            "width": "100%"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "width": "100%",
                "background-color": "#e4e4e4",
                "overflow": "hidden",
                "height": "200px",
                "display": "flex",
                "align-items": "center",
                "justify-content": "center",
                "position": "relative"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "style": {
                    "oveflow": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == '', 'auto', 'hidden')"
                  },
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "img",
                      "style": {
                        "width": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == '', '100%', '0'",
                        "height": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == '', '100px', '0'"
                      },
                      "attributes": {
                        "src": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == '', 'https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-react-assets/foldericons-fluent/folder-large_frontplate_nopreview.svg', '')"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "img",
                      "style": {
                        "width": "100%",
                        "height": "100%",
                        "display": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == '', 'none', '')"
                      },
                      "attributes": {
                        "src": "@thumbnail.300x300"
                      },
                      "defaultHoverField": "[$FileLeafRef]"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "margin": "15px 0",
                "position": "absolute",
                "top": "200px",
                "width": "100%"
              },
              "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontSize-14 ms-fontWeight-semibold"
              }
            },
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "flex-wrap": "wrap",
                "padding": "0 16px",
                "line-height": "20px",
                "width": "100%"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "style": {
                    "display": "inline-block",
                    "flex": "1 0 100%"
                  },
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "style": {
                        "color": "#a7a7a7",
                        "font-weight": "bold"
                      },
                      "txtContent": "Keywords"
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "forEach": "kwIterator in @currentField",
                          "elmType": "div",
                          "txtContent": "[$kwIterator]",
                          "attributes": {
                            "class": "ms-bgColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-white",
                            "title": "='keyword:' + =[$kwIterator]"
                          },
                          "style": {
                            "width": "16px",
                            "height": "16px",
                            "text-align": "center",
                            "margin": "1px"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "style": {
                    "display": "inline-block",
                    "flex": "1 0 34%"
                  },
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "style": {
                        "color": "#a7a7a7"
                      },
                      "txtContent": "=if([$AverageRating] >= 5, '*****', if([$AverageRating] >= 4, '****', if([$AverageRating] >= 3, '***', if([$AverageRating] >= 2, '**', if([$AverageRating] >= 1, '*', 'no rating'))))"
                    },
                    {
                      "elmType": "div",
                      "style": {
                        "color": "#a7a7a7",
                        "font-size": "40px"
                      },
                      "txtContent": "=if([$AverageRating] >= 5, '*****', if([$AverageRating] >= 4, '****', if([$AverageRating] >= 3, '***', if([$AverageRating] >= 2, '**', if([$AverageRating] >= 1, '*', '-'))))"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Any pointers to iterate through a delimited list of values would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, forEach does not support multiple lines of text type.

From **[this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#foreach)**:

The field used in the loop must be in a supported field type with multi-value option enabled: **Person, Lookup, and Choice**.

Since all the text in the multi-line text is recognized as a whole, we couldn't split it via ";" and add the link break between them with Json.